# $\mathbb C^{2 \times 2}$ be the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices ,and $T:\mathbb C^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}$ is a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb C^{2 \times 2}$ be the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb C$,and assume $T:\mathbb C^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}$ is a linear operator such that, for all $A \in \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}$, $T(A)=BA$, where $$B=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1& -1  \\
-4 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

What is the rank of $T$?

---

By **rank–nullity theorem** I know that :

$${\displaystyle \operatorname {Rank} (T)=\dim \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}}-\operatorname {Nullity} (T)$$
Where ${\displaystyle \operatorname {Nullity} (T):=\dim(\operatorname {Ker} (T)).}$

Kernel of $T$ is the set of all  $A \in \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}$ such that $$BA=0_{\mathbb C^{2 \times 2}}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0& 0  \\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad$$

From which I conclude that $$\text{kernel (T)}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1& x_2  \\
x_1& x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad:x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb C\right\}$$

I know that $\dim \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}=4$,so I only left with $\dim \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1& x_2  \\
x_1& x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad:x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb C\right\}$,and after that I can apply the theorem and determine the rank of the linear operator.

- So how can I find $\dim \text{kernel (T)}$?
- Besides what is the best way to determine the rank of $T$?

Comment: Your space Kernel(T) is a sub space of dimension 2. You can easily proove it by exhibiting a base of Kernel(T) made of 2 vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$\ker(T)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\\x_1&x_2\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,x_1,x_2\in\Bbb C\right\}$$and since $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ are two linearly independent matrices which span $\ker(T)$, $\dim\ker(T)=2$.

So,$$\operatorname{rank}(T)=4-\dim\ker(T)=4-2=2.$$

Comment: No! I just used the fact that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1&x_2\\x_1&x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right]=x_1\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]+x_2\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: ... which is to say, yes, experience. But it's not of the hard-earned kind.